Open the certificate store from a service
I'm trying to open the Windows certificate store from a service in C#, but it won't open.
It's not the first time I've created a service and it starts regularly but it doesn't open the certificate store and I don't understand why.
I don't get any error messages, it just doesn't open
This is the code that doesn't work:
            string[] aFiles = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.pdf");
            if (aFiles.Length > 0)
            {
                tSign.Stop();
                //Up to this point everything is fine, because it finds the pdf file, but then the         store doesn't open
                X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                X509Certificate2 certSelected = null;
                x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                //Maybe it's an asynchronous call and I don't see it?
                tSign.Start();
            }


Any suggestions? Thank you.
EDIT: this is the form of certificate selection:


Possibly permissions; services are typically launched under specific accounts; the account used for a given service might be highly privileged, but still might not have the permission required for the type of certificate store access attempted. Maybe also identity... "current user" would be the current user account under which the service is operating... is that intended?

Also what do you mean by "won't open" where is the code that verifies if it's open? Was there an exception?

The account I use is an administrator, when I say it doesn't open I simply mean that I don't see the certificate selection window.
The exact same procedure, used in an application and not in a service works perfectly.

What certificate selection window? x509Store.Open doesn't open windows, what are you talking about?

I added a screenshot of the certificate selection window in the question.

Ok, it seems like it's a general problem, not just certificates. The service is installed with SYSTEM user, but the startup of a program is started with another user.
There seems to be a way around it, but I haven't found it, so I'll look for another way
